# resolve-dnsname with Try/catch and set a variable

Tags: powershell, variables, error-handling, try-catch

Here is the scenario - I am running through a long list of domain names to audit them. Some of them no longer exist.

inside of my foreach loop I am doing the following among other things:

```
try{$nsrecords = Resolve-DnsName -name $name -Type NS}
catch{$active = 'False'}
```

The idea is that if the DNS Lookup fails for any reasons, Catch will catch the error and set the variable $active to 'False' that way, when the whole script runs in the end there will be a CSV output that says:

Domainname Active NameServer
test.co.nz True ns1.net.nz;ns2.net.nz
nondomian.co.nz false

however, when I run the Try/Catch with a domain I know doesn't exist anymore, the $active variable doesn't get set - I've not used try/catch before so I'm sure it's something basic that I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: Why not share the code itself so we can look at it. Also, does the error get displayed to the console? Have you tried using `-ErrorAction Stop` ?

Comment: The rest of the code isn't really relevant to the question - all I want is for when it fails a variable $active gets set to 'false'.

when it errors, it shows in the console:
Resolve-DnsName : non-domainname.co.nz: DNS name does not exist

Comment: The only explanation we can assume without looking at your code is that your error preference is not __Stop__ hence the exception is not getting caught and your `catch` block is not executed. And yes, seeing the code has all relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

```
    try {
            [system.net.dns]::resolve($address) | Select HostName,AddressList
        }
        catch 
        {
            $active = 'False'
        }
    }
```